# sum the last 12 cells in a row - excell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spread sheet with peoples attendance (In meetings). I need to know the absence count of every member.
The problem is that the table constantly "grows" (to the write), and I want the 3 cell (of every line) to have "The absence count of that row".
So the structure of the sheet is that the presence data is in lines 10-45, but the number of columns keeps growing. Today there is data in columns H-AK, but after the next meeting there will be an extra column so there will be data in columns H-AL.

Unfortunately I tried some things that I googled, but nothing seemed to be close.
Here is a picture of the spreadsheet

[image: picture of the spreadsheet]

Hope this is clear.
Thanks
zmau

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what have you researched / tried so far

Comment: Done, is this good enough ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Insert-> Table to convert your data to a table with headers. You can then reference the column names directly. This will preserve your formulas even if the number of columns in the table grows.

In the examples below I use the COUNTBLANK function to count the attendees of the meetings from the "Meeting 1" column through the "End" column. The formula for the "End" column is simply ="X" so that it is never blank.

As I add meetings (Insert -> Column immediately before the End column) the formulas don't need to be updated - they still work because they're based off of table column names.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I simply do not understand the answer. Probably because I am a very simple user.
I will add a sample of my spread sheet

Comment: Hi zmau, I'd try finding someone with knowledge of Excel to explain it to you in-person, or maybe check out some Excel videos online. Googling "Inserting a table in Excel" would be a good start.